# Issue with do while loop skipping past user input option

Tags: java, if-statement, passwords, boolean, do-while

This should be a program to take in a password from the user and check it against various parameters.

I've an issue with the do while loop, it prints:

```
Please enter your password.
Error. Password is too short. Try again.
```

Then it prints this after selecting option

```
1. Enter your own password for verification
```

The program should allow the user to enter a password before printing any error messages.

First time using this site. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

```
    import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.util.*;

public class CC_CA2
{


 // Main Method
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {      
      Scanner keyboardIn = new Scanner(System.in);  //Create Scanner object

      String[] data = {"123456","password","12345","12345678","qwerty","123456789","1234","baseball","dragon","football","1234567","monkey","letmein","abc123","111111","mustang","access","shadow","master","michael"}; 
      String correct;

      int numLetterCheck = 0;
      int option;

      boolean found = false;
      boolean check; 

      boolean digitFound = false;
      boolean letterFound = false;     


      //Menu
      System.out.println("Welcome to the password checker.");
      System.out.println("Would you like to:");
      System.out.println("1. Enter your own password for verification.");
      System.out.println("2. Have an easy to remember random password generated for you.");
      option = keyboardIn.nextInt();


      if (option==1)
      {

         do
         {  
            check = true;
            found=false;

            System.out.println("Please enter your password.");  // get user password
            correct = keyboardIn.nextLine();




            if (correct.length()<8)  // 1. check password > 8 characters
            {
               System.out.println("Error. Password is too short. Try again.");
               check=false;
               continue; 
            }

            if (correct.contains(" ")) //2. check if password contains any spaces
            {
               System.out.println("Error. Password contains a space. Try again.");
               check=false;
               continue; 
            }


            for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) // 3. check common passwords
            {
               if(data[i].equals(correct)) //if match found
               {           
                  found = true; //remember that it is found               
               }          
            }

            if(found) //if found is true
            {
               System.out.println("Error. This is a common password. Try again.");
               check=false;
               continue; 
            }



            for (char ch : correct.toCharArray())  // 4. Make sure password contains at least one letter and one number

            {
               if (Character.isDigit(ch))
               {
                  digitFound = true;
               }
               if (Character.isLetter(ch))
               {
                  letterFound = true;
               }

               if (digitFound && letterFound)
               {
                  numLetterCheck = 0;
               }
               else
               {
                  numLetterCheck = 1;               
               }
            } 

            while (numLetterCheck == 1)
            {

               letterFound=false;
               digitFound=false;

               System.out.println("Error. Password must contain at least one letter and one number. Try again.");
               correct = keyboardIn.nextLine();

                           }         


         }while(check == false);
      }
}}
```

Comment: If the variable correct is of buffer, you may be getting a different length than you expect. Try to print the length and see what you get.

Comment: Can you post a smaller example that reproduces your error? http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Hi, I edited your question, you need to approve my modification for it to be visible for everyone else. In general when using StackOverflow try to format your questions to make them more readable, it makes peoples more willing to read them. The syntax is intuitive but have a look at the How to Format box on the right when you write/edit a question or click the question-mark icon above the edit box.

Also, avoid posting big code classes like that when possible, try to extract a smaller test-case.

Comment: @robx Hi thanks for your response. I tried printing the length of the variable correct and it returned a value of 0. I printed it the line after correct = keyboardIn.nextLine(); inside the do while loop. Is this where you meant?

Comment: @ stackoverflow.com/help/mcve –  Reut Sharabani Hi thanks for getting back to me. I took out some of the code to try and make it more readable.

Comment: @ Daniele Segato Hi I accepted your edits and will read up on the correct formatting.

Comment: If length is 0 after you get the input that is the prob.